# How to neaten up a heatmap in seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I am plotting a correlation heatmap as follows:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,8))
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),annot=True, cmap = 'coolwarm')
```

and it is showing a plot as follows:

[image]

As it can be seen that the heatmap is not neatly made on the edges with the names and the values overlapping. Is there a way I can neaten it up to get a heatmap as follows:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try adding `square=True`. Also take a look at the last example [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).

Comment: It still generates kind of the same plot @Dan

Comment: Maybe do a `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))`, pass `ax` to `heatmap` and then try changing `ax.set_xlim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))
corr = df.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, 
            xticklabels=corr.columns.values,
            yticklabels=corr.columns.values,
               annot=True)
plt.show()
```